# Issue while applying filter combination in SO Jobs

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow-jobs

So I was checking out the SO Jobs and in tech filter I picked C# tag and in location I picked Australia, and what I got is an Alert Box and 500 in chrome's debug console.

[image: Img1]

[image: Img2]

However the same combination works with any other country. What happened to C# in Australia?

Chrome Version: 72.0.3626.96 and OS: Windows 10

Comment: There are only 24 jobs listed for Australia, so it's not that surprising there's no C# job.

Comment: When there is no match found, there's a message on UI that says "That's a miss". But, Here it's an alert , along with 500 response in chrome's developer tool console.

Comment: Actually there is 1 match and I can't reproduce your issue. Can you still reproduce it?

Comment: Yes I can still reproduce it at my end

Comment: Yeah I see it in the logs, something's throwing an System.IndexOutOfRangeException. Will dig.

Comment: @KaranDesai do you also get that error in an incognito window, or only when signed in?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I checked today in incognito. No error there.

Comment: @KaranDesai does the original error still reproduce? We suspect that it was a caching issue which should now be resolved.